# How to publish CDK project to npm and deploy after install

Tags: npm, npm-install, aws-cdk, npm-publish, npm-package

I would like to publish a CDK typescript project to npm repository. The project contains an app and a stack.
The what I would like to do is be able to install it by running `npm install my-package` and then just run `npm run mycustomscriptname`  to deploy the stack.
The `mycustomscriptname`is defined in my package.json in my cdk project like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "mycustomscriptname": "cdk deploy"
  },
```

I tried but after install I have a package.json with the following content

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-project": "^0.0.1"
  }
}
```

And all the cdk source code is located at `node_modules/my-project`
The package.json of my cdk project is also located at `node_modules/my-project`